# Sum of piecewise odd/even complex power series

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to solve the following problem:
Given

$$g(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$$

Where
$$a_n= f(x)=
\begin{cases}
 (n+1)(n+2)&\text{if}\,\ n\ \text{odd}\\
 \ 1&\text{if}\,\ n\ \text{even}\\
\end{cases}$$

Show that the radius of convergence ($\rho$) is 1 and that
$$ g(z)=\frac{1}{1-z^2}+(\frac{z^3}{1-z^2})^{''}$$
for $|z|<\rho$

I think I've managed the first part by splitting the series up into its even and uneven parts like this:
$$g(z)_{even}=\sum_{{n=0}}^{\infty}2n^2+6n+2\cdot z^{2n}$$
$$g(z)_{odd}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^{2n+1}$$

Both converge with radius of convergence 1, allowing me to conclude $g(z)$ converges with radius of convergence 1

But I am not sure about how to get started with the second part. I know that I 'just' need to differentiate $g(z)$ term by term, but I'm unsure about how to present $g(z)$ using the work I've already done.

Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: The sum of two power series with radius of convergence $1$ does not need to have radius of convergence $1$, e.g. $f = \sum z^n$ and $g = -f$, then $f+g$ has radius of convergence $\infty$. Hence you should really compute $\lim \sup |a_n/a_{n+1}|$.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate? My main issue is that I'm not sure how to represent $a_n$ in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea of splitting it up into the even and odd exponents.

We have:
\begin{alignat*}{2}
g(z) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n \\
&= \sum_{\substack{n=0\\n \ \text{even}}}^\infty z^n+\sum_{\substack{n=0\\n \ \text{odd}}}^\infty (n+1)(n+2) z^n&&\qquad \text{by splitting $g$ up}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{2n}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty ((2n+1)+1)((2n+1)+2) z^{2n+1} &&\qquad \text{by reindexing}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{2n}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty (2n+2)(2n+3) z^{2n+1} \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{2n}+\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty  z^{2n+3}\right)''\\
\end{alignat*}

Now, recall that the geometric series is $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n = \frac{1}{1-z}$$
and so we mold our results into something similar to this series:
\begin{alignat*}{2}
g(z) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{2n}+\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty  z^{2n+3}\right)''\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (z^2)^n+\left(z^3 \sum_{n=0}^\infty (z^2)^n\right)''\\
\end{alignat*}
Which gives you your answer after plugging it into the geometric series above.

Comment: Thanks so much! This was much more elaborate that I had hoped for.

Comment: You're welcome! :)